# Uploading files. How to avoid Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there any way to stop uploading when the file size is greater that any value?
I've tried to check `$_FILES['name']['size']`, but when it's a large file I'm getting the `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted` error.

The cause of this error is `memory_limit`, but I'd want to avoid the error even if the user tries to upload a very large file, so increasing this value won't do the trick.

How could I handle this error before sending an Internal Server Error to the client?

**Edit:**

The error comes from a Symfony2 line:

`$this->content = file_get_contents('php://input');`

So I'm guessing that the question is only applicable to Symfony2.

Comment: Add `&` to avoid errors warnings and notice.

Comment: Do you have any processing code to show us? If it's an issue in the script, you could take measures to prevent major use of memory.

Comment: @BaileyHerbert - I've updated my question. There are no issues, but when the user tries to upload a very large file.

Comment: The error shouldn't be with __uploading__ the file, but with __reading__ the file, so where/why are you reading the uploaded file?